# Как внести изменения данных, записанных в JTextField с помощью процедур Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

Здравствуйте, у меня возник такой вопрос и не могу пока что понять как реализовать такую задачу. Сначала создаю класс модели соединения с БД oracle:

```
public class DataBaseModel {
    Connection connection;              
    Statement statement;               
    ResultSet resultSet;
    ResultSetMetaData metaData;

public DataBaseModel(String url, String driverName, String user, String passwd){
    try {
    Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    System.out.println("Opening db connection");

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl",
            "SCOTT", "TIGER");   
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("Cannot find the database driver classes.");
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("Cannot connect to this database.");
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}

public void close() throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("Closing db connection");
    resultSet.close();
    statement.close();
    connection.close();
}

public void executeQuery(String query) {
    if (connection == null || statement == null) {
        System.err.println("There is no database to execute the query.");
        return;
    }
    try {
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);            
        metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();                                                 
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}
```

затем создаю java frame:

```
public class AddFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private final DataBaseModel dbm = new DataBaseModel("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl",
        "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", "SCOTT", "TIGER");
    private JTextField deptnoField;
    private JTextField dnameField;
    private JTextField locField;
    public AddFrame(){
        setTitle("Добавить строку в справочник");
        setSize(550, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                        BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED),
                        "Подразделения"),
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));
        JLabel deptnoLabel = new JLabel("ID подразделения");
        deptnoField = new JTextField(2);
        JLabel dnameLabel = new JLabel("Имя подразделения");
        dnameField = new JTextField(14);
        JLabel locLabel = new JLabel("Местоположение");
        locField = new JTextField(13);
        JButton addSaveButton = new JButton("Сохранить");
        addSaveButton.setToolTipText("Сохранить изменения");
        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                dbm.executeQuery("DECLARE BEGIN"
                                 + "SCOTT.dept_pkg.Add_Dept(" + deptnoField.getText() + ", "
                                 + dnameField.getText() + ", "
                                 + locField.getText() + ");"
                                 + "END;"
                                 + "/");
            }
        };
        addSaveButton.addActionListener(listener);
```

Пакет Oracle полностью рабочий и не сбоит, главная проблема в том что бы после нажатия на кнопку addSaveButton запрос посылался на БД. после запуска программы получаю вот такую вот ошибку:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: Строка 1, столбец 19: PLS-00103:
>   Встретился символ "." в то время как ожидалось одно из следующих:
>
> constant exception <идентификатор>    <идентификатор с двойными
>   кавычками-разделителями> таблица    long double ref симв. время
>   timestamp interval дата двоичн.    national символ nchar Символ
>   "<идентификатор>" заменен на ".", чтобы можно было продолжать.
>   ORA-06550: Строка 1, столбец 56: PLS-00103: Встретился символ "END" в
>   то время как ожидалось одно из следующих:
>
> begin function pragma процедура subtype тип <идентификатор>
>   <идентификатор с двойными кавычками-разделителями> current    cursor
>   удал. exists prior

Comment: Не силен в данном вопросе, но может быть не хватает пробела после DECLARE BEGIN

Comment: вот что получаю: java.sql.SQLException: Недействительный тип SQL: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED
после такого преобразования кода:
`dbm.executeQuery("DECLARE"
                                 + "BEGIN"
                                 + "SCOTT.dept_pkg.Add_Dept(" + deptnoField.getText() + ", "
                                 + dnameField.getText() + ", "
                                 + locField.getText() + ");"
                                 + "END;"
                                 + "/");`

Comment: Тут скорее всего видимо обстоит дело в том, что правильно ли я составил запрос?

Comment: Попробуй посмотреть на пробелы, которые ты не добавляешь.

Comment: В общем вот такой пакет:
`DECLARE
BEGIN
SCOTT.dept_pkg.Add_Dept(var1, var2, var3);
END;
/`

Comment: правильно ли я представил данный пакет в таком строчном виде:
`"DECLARE" + "BEGIN" + "SCOTT.dept_pkg.Add_Dept(" + deptnoField.getText() + ", "  + dnameField.getText() + ", "
+ locField.getText() + ");" + "END;" + "/"`

Comment: Тогда да, расставь пробелы в строках

Comment: Нет, не правильно ты представил данный пакет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимый пакет.

> DECLARE BEGIN SCOTT.dept_pkg.Add_Dept(var1, var2, var3); END; /

Нужный запрос выглядеть будет следующим образом

```
dbm.executeQuery("DECLARE BEGIN "
                 + "SCOTT.dept_pkg.Add_Dept(" + deptnoField.getText() + ", "
                 + dnameField.getText() + ", "
                 + locField.getText() + "); "
                 + "END;"
                 + " /");
```

Comment: вот что получил: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: Строка 1, столбец 63:
PLS-00103: Встретился символ "/" Символ "/" опущен.

Comment: Судя по всему этому вместо этого символа надо представить какую то альтернативу

Comment: Я уже и так пробовал, не получается хоть тресни.
`dbm.executeQuery(String.format("DECLARE\n BEGIN\n SCOTT.dept_pkg.Add_Dept(%s, %s, %s);\n"
                        + " END;\n /", deptnoField.getText(), dnameField.getText(), locField.getText()));`

Comment: Зачем ты делаешь \n около DECLARE и BEGIN? \n - это перевод строки. Тебе просто пробел нужен

Comment: я сделал вот так :
`dbm.executeQuery(String.format("DECLARE\n BEGIN\n SCOTT.dept_pkg.Add_Dept(%s, '%s', '%s');\n END;", deptnoField.getText(), dnameField.getText(), locField.getText()));`

Comment: и все заработало, но для отображения данных в таблицу надо пере подключится к ней